# How to save data in Service Class Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, service, background, save

I'm trying to save my values from activity.

How to save this values in Service class to database at background

and create response.

```
if (idBoolean && nameBoolean && priceBoolean && vatRateBoolean) {

    val bundle = Bundle(4)
    bundle.putString("PRODUCT_ID",productId)
    bundle.putString("PRODUCT_NAME",productName)
    bundle.putString("PRICE",price)
    bundle.putString("VAT RATE",vatRate)


    Intent(this,RegistryService::class.java).also {
        it.putExtra("SALE_ACTION",bundle)
        startService(it)
    }
}
```

if boolean's true, I will sent this values to Service class with bundle.

And take like this in Service class;

```
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {

    val saleBundle = intent?.getBundleExtra("SALE_ACTION")
    saleBundle?.let {
        val bundleId = it.get("PRODUCT_ID").toString()
        val bundleName = it.get("PRODUCT_NAME").toString()
        val bundlePrice = it.get("PRICE").toString()
        val bundleVatRate = it.get("VAT RATE").toString()
    }

    Thread {
        while (true) { }
    }
    return START_STICKY
}
```

I want to start a response, listen and receive result to activity and

save this values with 6 Columns;

ProductId

Productname

Price

VatRate:

Status : 1) WaitsPayment 2) PaymentCancelled 3) PaymentCompleted

PaymentType: 0) None, 1) Cash, 2) Credit, 3) QRCode)

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do this with a Service? It is considerably more difficult than doing it with a coroutine or executor and not really justified for such a trivial amount of data to write.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Yes, this what is asked. I need to do with this way.

Comment: If you want to communicate back to the Activity, you need to bind to the service instead of using `startService`. You should start with the documentation on services to see how to bind to a service and use IBinder to communicate back to an Activity.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I did check all documentation about service, that confused me more :D I didnt understand how to implement. I need to see a little bit close sample to mine situation.